# WPF, how to make JAWS read a text element without focusing it?

Tags: wpf, jaws-screen-reader

Is it possible in WPF to make JAWS read the content of a text block without focusing on it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if WPF has this concept but in HTML, you can have an [`aria-live`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) region and when you inject new text into it, the screen reader reads it without the focus moving to it.

Comment: I found similar idea in wpf as per the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699145/automationproperties-livesetting-not-working-in-wpf-in-net-framework-4-7-1/52703808
But this solution does not work with JAWS 2019 screen reader. Does aria-live works with JAWS?

Comment: Yes, `aria-live` is well supported by all screen readers and browsers.  It looks like `AutomationProperties.LiveSetting` is the correct thing to do from the link you found, but set the value to "Polite" instead of "Assertive".  That probably won't change your results but using "Polite" is the normal setting for live regions.  "Assertive" should only be used for extremely important messages.