# WPF, AutomationProperties.LiveSettings does not work with JAWS 2019

Tags: wpf, jaws-screen-reader

I tried to implement the idea exactly as per the below link:
[AutomationProperties.LiveSetting not working in WPF in .NET Framework 4.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699145/automationproperties-livesetting-not-working-in-wpf-in-net-framework-4-7-1/52703808)
using JAWS 2019 in .NET framework 4.7.1 .

Unfortunately the solution does not seem to work in JAWS. Is it the bug in JAWS or am I missing something.

I was expecting JAWS to read the changed content whenever the live region changed event has been raised. But nothing happens. Please help.